# Output feature missing when using Cluster and Outlier Analysis (Anselin Local Moran's I) in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.4, moran-index

I am currently working on a project which I must calculate [Anselin Local Moran's I](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-statistics-toolbox/h-how-cluster-and-outlier-analysis-anselin-local-m.htm). I am using polygon features and `ArcMap 10.4.1`. Here is my problem: when I am trying to run the command `ArcMap` shows no problem running the command but the output feature is never created. I have double checked the Path of the output feature! Any thoughts of what might goes wrong?

Answer (score 1):

What Moran's I tool are you using specifically? There are two, one of which creates a separate output:

[Spatial Autocorrelation (Global Moran's I)](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/tools/spatial-statistics-toolbox/spatial-autocorrelation.htm)

[Cluster and Outlier Analysis (Anselin Local Moran's I)](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/tools/spatial-statistics-toolbox/cluster-and-outlier-analysis-anselin-local-moran-s.htm)
I would check your Geoprocessing > Results to verify the tool you are using and it will also indicate to you where your output file is located under: Output Feature Class. If you right-click > Add-to display it will add it to your current ArcMap session. My guess is it might be saving to your default gdb `ArcGIS\Default.gdb\`.

Comment: I am using Cluster and Outlier Analysis (Anselin Local Moran's I) tool. Thank you for your reply.
I have found the solution. I just have closed ArcMap and re-opened it and the problem solved.